# NodeJS, express: validating request json payload on server to check JSON is not corrupt

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, post

I am trying to develop a service to process some JSON data that is sent by a client in a POST request. I have developed the service and the functionality and it works fine if the JSON data in POST request is free of errors but if the json data in request is corrupt (missing a brace or comma) then the service breaks. I am new with node and tried error handling with try catch but that does not seem to work. Can someone please have a look at this code and error and help me figure out how to handle the errors properly in node.js

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/', function(request, response){

response.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
var jsonObj = request.body;
var responseJson = {};
if(jsonObj.hasOwnProperty("payload"))
{
var keyResponse = "response";
responseJson[keyResponse] = "Here is processed data";
response.status(200);
}
else
{
    response.status(400);
    var keyResponse = "error";
    responseJson[keyResponse] = "JSON parsing failed";
}
response.send(responseJson);
})
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port);
console.log("Sever is up and listening on port "+port);
```

Errors:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token p in JSON at position 6
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at parse (/Users/Vov/Desktop/NineEntertainmentService/nine-service/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:88:17)
at /Users/Vov/Desktop/NineEntertainmentService/nine-service/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:116:18
at invokeCallback (/Users/Vov/Desktop/NineEntertainmentService/nine-service/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:262:16)
at done (/Users/Vov/Desktop/NineEntertainmentService/nine-service/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:251:7)
at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/Users/Vov/Desktop/NineEntertainmentService/nine-service/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:307:7)
at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
```

This is an error from when I fed a request with JSON data missing a colon(:)

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: "tried error handling with try catch but that does not seem to work" — I can't see that attempt anywhere in the code you've provided.

Comment: @Quentin I have removed try catches now but earlier I had put try around the "app.use(bodyParser.json());" and "var jsonObj = request.body;" which did not work after reading on several forums I think it's because of the async code, not sure though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add an error-handling middleware to respond to that specific error.

[Difficult to determine that an error is the result of bad JSON](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/issues/122)

```js
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  if (err instanceof SyntaxError && err.status === 400 && 'body' in err) {
    // Handle the error here
    console.error('Bad JSON');
    res.status(500).send('JSON parse error');
  }
  
  // Pass the error to the next middleware if it wasn't a JSON parse error
  next(err):
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying! but how can I use this structure with the app.post() method?

Comment: From what i understood, your error occurs even before the request hits the POST-route. If you add the error-handling middleware to the code, the error will pass through it when any error in your request/response chain is raised. Read more about error middlewares here https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

Comment: I also was thinking of the same thing about the error occurring before post but wasnt able to figure out where to place the error handling code. figured it out now. Thank you for the help!